# A synonym for "circumvent" which does not have connotations of deception

Tags: synonyms, business-language

I'd like to circumvent a regulation in a way which does not imply that I have been sneaky or deceptive. I have used a justified alternative method to avoid being subject to the regulation.

Comment: In a list of synonyms, 'bypass' seems to me the least pejorative, and 'dodge' the most.

Comment: I would use "circumvent".

Answer (score 1):

The word you want is *avoidance*. It is specifically differentiated from *evasion* in just the way you have described.

[An example usage](http://www.geocities.ws/noelcox/Tax.htm)

> Tax and Regulatory Avoidance Through Non-traditional Alternatives to Tax Havens

Answer (score 0):

from: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/loophole

**loophole**

noun

1: An ambiguity or inadequacy in the law or a set of rules.

‘they exploited tax loopholes’

from: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/workaround

**workaround**

noun

"A method for overcoming a problem or limitation in a program or system".

in this case you have "worked around" a particular regulation.

Comment: "Loophole" is fairly pejorative.

Comment: Being pejorative may well depend on which side you stand. If you’re the drafter of the regulation you may think so, if your paid (or paying someone) to work within the regulations it may be seen as genius. 

In any case the OP asked for a way that didn’t imply sneaky of deceptive behaviour (as they obviously felt “circumvent” did) , finding loopholes is neither of these things (even if you think it’s pejorative) as it usually takes great skill and ingenuity and is explicitly not cheating/rule breaking.